# How to test a bootstrap modal using Behat/Mink and selenium standalone server

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, behat, mink

I just want to do a quick entry about one thing I've been trying for a long time and I just recently found an easy way of doing. I will test a bootstrap modal using Behat/Mink and selenium standalone server.

Tools:

- "behat/behat v3.*"
- "behat/mink v1.7"
- "behat/mink-extension v2.2"
- "behat/mink-selenium2-driver v*"
- "Firefox 46.0.1"
- "selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1"

First of all we need init behat and configure it. In my case, I'm storing all my tests inside a folder named behat wish is located insde a folder named tests.

See bellow how looks the folder structure:

> - root_file
>
>   - folder 1
>   - folder 2
>   - folder n
>   - tests
>
>     - behat
>
>       - context
>       - gherkin
>   - behat.yml

Basically all my context classes will be inside the context folder and all my features will be inside the gherkin folder.

Next step will add your configuration in the behat.yml file. There you can define all your profiles, suites, variables, etc. Notice in the `default` suite, inside filters `~@javascript` tags, with that we are telling to behat that exclude all the features tagged as `@javascript` from that context. Also, notice in the second suite `(browser)`, in this case we are telling to behat that execute only the features tagged as `@browser`.

See bellow how looks the behat.yml:

```
default:
    suites:
        default:
            paths: [%paths.base%/tests/behat/gherkin/custom.feature]
            contexts: [Tests\behat\features\FeatureContext]
            filters:
                tags: ~@javascript

        # Browser inteaction
        browser:
            paths: [%paths.base%/tests/behat/gherkin/browser.feature]
            contexts: [Tests\behat\features\BrowserContext]
            filters:
                tags: "@browser"

    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            selenium2: ~
                #wd_host: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"
            base_url: "http://localhost/"
```

Next we need to create a feature with at least one scenario to test. In this case we have to assume there is a web page with a button that triggers the modal and the modal will contain the text "Hello wold!"

See bellow how looks this feature:

```
Feature: Testing a bootstrap modal
   In order test javascript with behat/mink
   As a user
   I want to check a bootstrap modal

   @javascript @browser
   Scenario: Check a bootstrap modal text
      Given I am on "some-page"
      When I press "some-button"
      Then An alert modal should show up with:
      """
      Hello world!
      """
```

Finally, this is how looks the context:

```
<?php 

use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase as PHPUnit;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;

class BrowserContext extends MinkContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext 
{
    private $baseUrl;

    public function __construct($baseUrl = "http://localhost/") 
    {
        $this->baseUrl = $baseUrl;
    }

    /**
     * @Then An alert modal should show up with:
     */
    public function anAlertModalShouldShowUpWith(PyStringNode $message) 
    {
        //prepare the js script
        //here we are checking if th emodal is visible
        $script = "(function(){return ($('#myModal').is(':visible'));})();";

        //store the result of the js code
        $result = $this->getSession()->evaluateScript($script);

        //check for true with phpunit
        PHPUnit::assertTrue($result);

        //prepare the js script
        //here we are getting all the modal html as a string
        $script = "(function(){return $('#myModal').html();})();";

        //store the result of the js code
        $result = $this->getSession()->evaluateScript($script);

        //check if the string contains our message
        PHPUnit::assertContains($message->getRaw(), $result);
    }
}
```

And that is all. Now you need to start selenium and execute the tests.

Hope this could be useful to someone.

Cheers.